# why is html in java not working?

Tags: java, html

when i use this code it does not work; the text does not become bold. Why?

```
    label1 = new JLabel();
    label1.setText("Welcome, <html><strong>Hussein</strong></html>.");
```

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790500/render-html-in-swing-application

Answer (score 4):

Your HTML syntax is bad, since your `String` does not start with the `html` DOM root.

Try something in the lines of:

```
label1.setText("<html>Welcome <strong>Hussein</strong>.</html>");
```

Find a tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html).

Comment: Maybe also add a body tag?

Comment: @DejaVu nope. Not necessary.

Comment: @DejaVu "To specify that a component's text has HTML formatting, just put the <html> tag at the beginning of the text, then use any valid HTML in the remainder." http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html

Comment: @DejaVu this is 1) not a script 2) conforms to API, which implies that 3) html in Swing components does not have to fully conform to w3c standards.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add body tag ,Try This :

```
label1 = new JLabel();
    label1.setText("<html><body>Welcome ,<strong> Hussein</strong></body></html>");
```

Comment: i have edited, it wont accept , if we enter text with mixed type string+html tag. it will be working fine as you want here.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("<html><yourTagHere><yourOtherTagHere>this is your text</yourOtherTagHere></yourTagHere></html>");
```

Answer (score -1):

Why are you mixing html and java.  tag is in html. This is how you do in java

```
label = new JLabel("A label");
label.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 14));
```

Comment: i only wanted a part to be in bold, not all of it. I am aware of this and i do use it.

Comment: Then , you should mention in your question , saying clearly that you want it only for **some part of text**

Comment: @Stunner Your answer is saying that you can't use html in a JLabel component (or not even in Java), which is not true.